# How do I pass data from widgets with multiple PendingIntents?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-widget

```
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, RecipeDetailActivity.class);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, RecipeDetailActivity.class);
    Intent intent3 = new Intent(context, RecipeDetailActivity.class);
    Intent intent4 = new Intent(context, RecipeDetailActivity.class);

    intent1.putExtra("id", (long) 1);
    intent1.putExtra("name", "Nutella Pie");

    intent2.putExtra("id", (long) 2);
    intent2.putExtra("name", "Brownies");

    intent3.putExtra("id", (long) 3);
    intent3.putExtra("name", "Yellow Cake");

    intent4.putExtra("id", (long) 4);
    intent4.putExtra("name", "Cheesecake");

    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent3 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent4 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent4, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.tv_recipe1, pendingIntent1);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.tv_recipe2, pendingIntent2);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.tv_recipe3, pendingIntent3);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.tv_recipe4, pendingIntent4);
```

EDIT: I put different request codes and used OnNewIntent method in the activity. Now works.

I have 4 views in a widget. If I press on the first one, I should open the activity with id = 1, but if second, then open the activity with id = 2, and so on.

`views` is a `RemoteViews` object. The `RecipeDetailActivity` will act on showing data depending on the intent data (id and name). That activity contains a fragment, and when created, set the data to the fragment, then the fragment will update its information async.

It's not working, as clicking on all of them will yield the same result (currently at id = 3). Shouldn't they cancel each other so that when I open a new one give a new intent (or open a completely new activity)?

Comment: Pass a different `requestCode` - the second parameter in `PendingIntent.getActivity()` - for each, instead of `1` for all of them.

Comment: And I thought if they were the same they knew that they will cancel each other. I also added OnNewIntent in the activity to handle the change. Thanks.